# A sector angle of a circle with radius $9$ cm measures $5π/12$. What is the perimeter of the sector?

Tags: trigonometry

I started by using the Arc length = ($\theta$)(radius), where $\theta$ is angle measure in radians.

I got $(5\pi/12)(9 \text{ cm}) = 45 \pi/12 \text{ cm} \approx 11.78 \text{ cm}$

The answer in the book is $(15\pi + 72)/4, \approx 29.78 \text{ cm}$, but I have no clue how I got that or if I'm interpreting the question correctly.

Is it not asking for the length of the arc subtended by $5\pi/12$? I don't know if sector and arc are the same thing or not.

Comment: $\displaystyle 11.78 + 9 + 9 = 29.78$

Answer (score 1):

The perimeter of a [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) includes two radii of the circle as well as some of the circle.  Your answer matches the first term in the parentheses, the $15\pi$.  The other term accounts for the two radii.

Comment: Thank you! I had no clue what the difference between a sector or arc was. That makes sense!